# htaccess redirect to slim document root outside of public directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to redirect a user from the domain `localhost/Projects/Applications/File%20Hosting/src` to the document root of `localhost/Projects/Applications/File%20Hosting/src/public`. Inside my public folder I have the following `.htaccess` file that slim tells you to use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

How would I be able to setup an `.htaccess` one level up from the `public` folder that will essentially move all traffic to the public directory? Thanks.

Comment: Some clarification is needed. If the document root is `/public`, how are any web requests reaching the parent `/src` to begin with? By nature of being outside the document root it should be completely inaccessible to HTTP requests unless there's an Alias in the server or virtualhost config.

Comment: Is `/src` the docroot of a different VirtualHost? You used the term "domain" when referring to it, which maybe implies it is.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski This is actually a plugin of sorts that I'm making. THe user will be able to install it via a sub domain which will require no other setup than just setting the root to `/public` but if they decide to install it via a directory such as `/hosting` I will need to have a way for it to redirect to the `public` folder. Is there a way where a website can have multiple roots that I'm not aware of?

Comment: In your hypothentical, what is `/hosting`? Is it the filesystem directory serving as the `/` document root for web requests? And in that case, does your project become `/hosting/public`?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski For example I'm making this for my website so I can have a simple personal file hosting service. I'll have my main website `https://website.net` and then I'll have `https://website.net/hosting`. Since the project is Slim I need a front controller via the `public` folder. The domain for hosting should just be `https://website.com/hosting` which will remap to `/public`